# polymer 2.0 web app doesnt work on firefox and Edge

Tags: polymer-2.x

Hi why could be that whis web page works fine in Chrome but not in firefox and Edge? [Example](http://intercercas.com)

I cant find why :( and I dont know how to search the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace your line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```